# Showing users nearby locations based off radius

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geocode

I am building a google map that shows users the nearest locations. I have a json file for now, but will be used with a database later on. I need to show users locations based off a certain radius. Below is a component built trying to accomplish that. When I setState it only captures the last element in the array. Im not sure why.

```
        Geocode.setApiKey("apikey");
        Geocode.setLocationType("ROOFTOP");
        const distances = [
          {
            value: 50,
            label: "50",
          },
          {
            value: 150,
            label: "150",
          },
          {
            value: 250,
            label: "250",
          },
          {
            value: 500,
            label: "500",
          },
        ];
        
        //Gathers location and calculates distances then sets state of that distance
        
function Map() {
          const classes = useStyles();
        // sets state
          const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});
          const [center] = useState({ lat: 43.211243, lng: -112.413304 });
          const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState({});
          const [input, setInput] = useState("");
          const [nearestPlace, setNearestPlace] = useState([]);
          const [miles, setMiles] = React.useState(50);
        
            // gets user location
          useEffect(() => {
            geocode();
          }, []);
          // Grabs users location
          const geocode = async () => {
            let location = input;
            await axios
              .get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", {
                params: {
                  address: location,
                  key: "apikey",
                },
              })
              .then((response) => {
                const { lat, lng } = response.data.results[0].geometry.location;
                setUserLocation({ lat, lng }); // sets user location
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          };
    //calculation of lat and lng
          function distance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, miles) { 
            // miles optional
            if (typeof miles === "undefined") {
              miles = false;
            }
            function deg2rad(deg) {
              return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
            }
            function square(x) {
              return Math.pow(x, 2);
            }
            var r = 6371; // radius of the earth in km
            lat1 = deg2rad(lat1);
            lat2 = deg2rad(lat2);
            var lat_dif = lat2 - lat1;
            var lng_dif = deg2rad(lng2 - lng1);
            var a =
              square(Math.sin(lat_dif / 2)) +
              Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * square(Math.sin(lng_dif / 2));
            var d = 2 * r * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
            if (miles) {
              return d * 0.621371;
            } //return miles
            else {
              return d;
            } //return km
          }
        // this is where I get tripped up. Its not working properly

          const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            geocode();
            let nearest = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
              nearest.push(
                distance(
                  userLocation.lat,
                  userLocation.lng,
                  locations[i].location.lat,
                  locations[i].location.lng,
                  "miles"
                )
              );
            }
            const result = nearest.map((item) => {
              let closest = [];
              if ((miles === "50" && item <= 50) || item <= 100) {
                closest.push(item);
                return closest;
              }
            });
        
            result.forEach((el) => {
              if (el === "undefined") {
                return;
              } else {
                 console.log(el) // this provides the correct values
                setNearestPlace(el); // Here is where it wont set my state to the values
                console.log(nearestPlace);
              }
              return el;
            });
          };
        
          const onSelect = (item) => {
            setSelected(item);
          };
          const handleChange = (event) => {
            setMiles(event.target.value);
          };
        
          return (
            <>
              <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="apikey">
                <GoogleMap
                  className={classes.map}
                  mapContainerStyle={mapStyles}
                  zoom={7}
                  center={center}
                >
                  {locations.map((item) => {
                    return (
                      <Marker
                        key={item.name}
                        position={item.location}
                        onClick={() => onSelect(item)}
                      />
                    );
                  })}
        
                  {selected.location && (
                    <InfoWindow
                      position={selected.location}
                      clickable={true}
                      onCloseClick={() => setSelected({})}
                    >
                      <div>
                        {selected.image ? (
                          <img
                            alt="spudnik"
                            style={{ width: "200px" }}
                            src={selected.image}
                          />
                        ) : null}
                        <p>{selected.name}</p>
                        <p>{selected.address}</p>
                        <p>{selected.phone}</p>
                      </div>
                    </InfoWindow>
                  )}
                </GoogleMap>
              </LoadScript>
              <div className={classes.formControl}>
                <form
                  className={classes.form}
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                  autoComplete="on"
                >
                  <div>
                    <TextField
                      className={classes.input}
                      onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                      value={input}
                      size="small"
                      id="outlined-basic"
                      variant="outlined"
                      InputProps={{
                        endAdornment: (
                          <InputAdornment position="end">
                            <SearchIcon className={classes.searchIcon} />
                          </InputAdornment>
                        ),
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </form>
                <div>
                  <Select
                    native
                    value={miles}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label="Age"
                    inputProps={{
                      name: "miles",
                      id: "outlined-age-native-simple",
                    }}
                  >
                    <option aria-label="None" value="" />
                    <option value={50}>50</option>
                    <option value={100}>100</option>
                    <option value={150}>150</option>
                    <option value={200}>200</option>
                    <option value={250}>250</option>
                    <option value={500}>500</option>
                  </Select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          );
        }
        
        export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here

```
result.forEach((el) => {
  if (el === "undefined") {
    return;
  } else {
    console.log(el) // this provides the correct values
    setNearestPlace(el); // Here is where it wont set my state to the values
    console.log(nearestPlace);
  }
  return el;
});
```

You are calling `setNearestPlace()` in a loop and passing the array element as an argument. As a result, the last value passed, i.e. the last element of the array will be your final state.

I believe you are trying to do something like this instead

```
setNearestPlace(result.filter(ele => Boolean(ele))); // Boolean(ele) check whether the ele is null or undefined.
```